# Ошибка при добавлении элементов в ViewFlipper android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, android-viewflipper

Я ставлю обработчик пролистывания для `LinearLayout`, в котором находится `ViewFlipper`, нахожу `ViewFlipper` и пытаюсь добавить к нему 3 элемента:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ...

    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_linear_layout_1);
    mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);

    ...

    flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_viewFlipper_1);

    flipper.addView(makeLayout_1());
    flipper.addView(makeLayout_2());
    flipper.addView(makeLayout_3());
}
```

но на строках:

```
flipper.addView(makeLayout_1());
flipper.addView(makeLayout_2());
flipper.addView(makeLayout_3());
```

приложение вылетает...

Вот методы, через которые я получаю `View` (потом буду дописывать):

```
private View makeLayout_1() {
    return getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_1, null);
}
private View makeLayout_2() {
    return getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_2, null);
}
private View makeLayout_3() {
    return getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_3, null);
}
```

`layout` разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="ТАБЛИЦА 1"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="ТАБЛИЦА 2"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="ТАБЛИЦА 3"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

И stacktrace ошибки:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f04002b
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5624)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f04002b
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1457)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2904)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1237)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.MainActivity.makeWords(MainActivity.java:59)
            at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5624)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

---

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `            at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.MainActivity.makeWords(MainActivity.java:59)` — ошибка здесь. Метод `makeWords`, 59-я строка файла `MainActivity`. Там есть айдишник какого-то ресурса, который он найти не может. Если не сможешь разобраться — добавь к вопросу сам тот метод.

Comment: @ДаниярСупиев, я засунул в новый проект то же, что и у меня в основной программе, только имена поменял (чтобы не путаться). Закинуть код основной программы?

Comment: Так глюк у тебя в основном проекте или в новом? Пока что просто дай метод `makeWords`. И, желательно, найди ресурс, который там вызывается. Если он вообще существует. Если его нет — проблема в этом.

Comment: @ДаниярСупиев, в обоих... Секунду :).

Comment: @ДаниярСупиев, пока копировал код — нашел ошибку! Я засунул `layout` файлы в папки `layout-land`... Добавьте Ваш ответ, про то что файлы не находит. Я приму.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В комментариях к вопросу выяснилось, что проблема в заключалась в том, что требуемый ресурс существовал только в layout-land, но не в layout.